# Formulating and solving a linear programming/assignment problem in python

Tags: python, optimization, variable-assignment

I've got a case where I need to allocate people into groups/days. I want to do it in a way that maximizes the number of people on each day.

Constraint - A person cannot be part of 2 consecutive days (ie. Person A cannot be part of Days 1 and 2 or 2 and 3. However, he/she can be part of Days 1 and 3)

Here's a snapshot of what the data looks like:

```
Person | Group/Day
A      | 1
A      | 2
A      | 3
B      | 2
B      | 4
B      | 1
C      | 2
D      | 4
D      | 3
```

I've tried using a FIFO approach, but its less than ideal since I end up with days with very few people.

I've managed to do this in pandas/python using loops and groupby, but its not very efficient because it takes too long

Is this something that can be solved using linear programming? I'm not sure how to quantify this into a linear problem.

Answer (score 0):

(If I got the question wrong, let me know.)

How can we group the most amount of people per day?
If a person shows up everyday they can, but cannot show up two days in a row, then the days they can show up is either every even day or every odd day, like:

```
# person = [list of days]
PersonA = [1,3,5,7]
PersonB = [2,4,6,8]
```

The math equations for the are:
Even numbers: f(x) = 2x     # it is always even because every number times 2 is even
Odd numbers:  f(x) = 2x+1   # it is always odd because any even number plus 1 is odd

For the total days possible per person, you only need to take the total amount of days and divide by 2.

In python, you can have simple expressions for checking either even or odd numbers:

```
If (x%2 == 0): print(f'{x} is even'})
If (x%2 == 1): print(f'{x} is odd'})
```

However, if the person doesn't show at every chance they get, you can test for valid days by taking two consecutive days A and B of a list L and checking if B is not equal to A-1. Like this:

```
array = [a,b,c,d]

# b and c being integers
if (c+1 == b):
  print('list of days not valid for this person')
```

Comment: Thanks Gulliver, the first assumption might be flawed.

The days will be fixed beforehand, so for a person A - one solution could be days 1,4,6 (which will be a mix of odd and even days)

Comment: @Guiliver For the record, you were actually right in your last answer. They had `findall`, but the actual alias is `findAll`. I'm sorry I wasn't more cautious (although I'll also note that I'm not the one that downvoted you).

Comment: It is ok! I would've guessed findAll was also a typo - so I was wrong anyways. But thank you for the note!